# What is wrong with the following code to identify balanced parentheses using stack?

Tags: c++, stl, stack

Problem:

Given a sequence consisting of parentheses, determine whether the expression is balanced. A sequence of parentheses is balanced if every open parentheses can be paired uniquely with a closed parentheses that occurs after the former. Also, the interval between them must be balanced. You will be given three types of parentheses: (, {, and [.

{[()]} - This is a balanced parentheses.

{[(])} - This is not a balanced parentheses.

Input Format:

*The first line of input contains the number of test cases.

*Each test case consists of a single line with the sequence of parentheses.

```
stack <char> stk;
int main() {
/* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */   
int n;

cin>>n;

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    string s;
    cin>>s;cout<<s;
    int j=0;
    while(j!=s.length())
    {
        if(stk.size()==0&&(s[j]==')'||s[j]==']'||s[j]=='}'))
        {stk.push('z');}
        if(s[j]=='('||s[j]=='['||s[j]=='{')
            stk.push(s[j]);
        if(stk.top()=='('&&s[j]==')')
            stk.pop();
        if(stk.top()=='['&&s[j]==']')
            stk.pop();
        if(stk.top()=='{'&&s[j]=='}')
            stk.pop();   
        j++;
    }
    if(stk.size()==0)
        cout<<"YES"<<endl;
    else
    {
        cout<<"NO"<<endl;
        while(stk.size()!=0)
            stk.pop();
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

It is a code for checking for balanced parentheses. Its working fine with strings starting with a '{' but fails with strings like "[]"

Comment: Instead of `stk.push('z')` you can just set a boolean `invalid` to true and do a `break;` out of the loop.

Comment: Here's a clue: try swapping: `if(stk.top()=='['&&s[j]==']')` and `if(stk.top()=='{'&&s[j]=='}')` and see how things change.

Comment: PS: The problem is trivially solvable by making use of short-circuit boolean evaluation.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, that doesn't really help to solve the issue. Thanks

Comment: @CraigYoung, that one did it. Thanks!

Comment: @Nanda: Well, you're clarifying that you're unwilling to learn, and would rather just be able to hand in this assignment. Why did you do that?

Answer (score 1):

You must be getting a Segmentation Fault.

Suppose,

```
s = "[]";
```

After 1st iteration your stack contains only "[".

During 2nd iteration,

```
if(stk.top()=='['&&s[j]==']')
        stk.pop();
```

above code makes your stack empty.
In next line you are calling

```
stk.top() // But your stack is empty
```

in

```
if(stk.top()=='{'&&s[j]=='}')
        stk.pop();
```

This is the problem. So before calling

```
stk.top();
```

make sure that your stack is not empty.

Check [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-for-balanced-parentheses-in-an-expression/) tutorial on balanced parentheses.

Comment: That really helped. Thanks a lot